# Creating RDS instances from not the recent snapshot using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In Terraform project I am creating an RDS instance from a not recent snapshot (fifth before the last), my script here:

```
data "aws_db_snapshot" "db_snapshot" {
  db_instance_identifier = "production-db-intern"
  db_snapshot_arn = "arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:123114111478:snapshot:rds:production-db-intern-2019-05-09-16-10"
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "db_intern" {
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  identifier = "db-intern"
  auto_minor_version_upgrade = false
  instance_class = "db.m4.4xlarge"
  deletion_protection = false
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_id}"]
  db_subnet_group_name = "${var.subnet_group_name}"

  timeouts {
    create = "3h"
    delete = "2h"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  snapshot_identifier = "${data.aws_db_snapshot.db_snapshot.id}"
}
```

I did a "terraform plan" and
I got the next error:

```
Error: data.aws_db_snapshot.db_snapshot: "db_snapshot_arn": this field cannot be set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db_snapshot_arn` is not a valid field of the `aws_db_snapshot` data resource. Did you mean `db_snapshot_identifier`.

Also, you can't pass the ARN to this data resource, you can pass the snapshot ID instead, e.g. `snap-1234567890abcdef0`.

Besides that, the data resource only expects either the `db_instance_identifier` to be set or the `db_snapshot_identifier`. See the [documentation on the snapshot CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-snapshots.html) for more details on the specifics. Terraform leverages the CLI to retrieve these resources.